# Calendar events form entire Lotus Notes

Tags: rest, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm trying to fetch all events from entire system by using REST API to synchronize with own application. I was extracting events for every user using REST API for his own calendar file.

For example:

*Fetch johndoe.nsf/api/calendar/events*

*Fetch jasonmartin.nsf/api/calendar/events*

*Fetch jeanmoore.nsf/api/calendar/events*

etc.

It's working with low number of users. **But I need to do it for around 2,5k users**, which kills my system.

Is there any central database from I can extract this data?
I tried this with resource reservation databese, but only what I got was empty response.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no central database of calendar events. There couldn't be. Notes and Domino is a distributed environment. Information can be spread over dozens of servers.

But you could write Java or C application that runs on the Domino server and aggregates the information from all the users' calendars into one central database, and that application will probably run faster than your remote calls through the REST API. But you'll still have to make REST API calls into that central database, and the sum of the activity will be greater than what you are dealing with now.

Comment: Well, maybe my answer is late, but i found a solution for my problem.
The deal was to create a view using Domino Designer in a resource reservation database, which outputs all reservations categorized by date. I am able to get data from this view using LOTUS data API. 


I am getting all events only by using one request. The problem is that Lotus Notes administrator needs to create a new view in database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my iCal freeware tool could help you
http://abdata.ch/publish-ibm-domino-calendar-entries-in-icalendar-format/